# Topology: Union of connected sets

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ be a topological space, and assume that the sets $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ are connected. Assume
also that $A_i\cap A_{i+1}$ is nonempty, for every $i = 1, \ldots, n-1$.

Prove that $\bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i$ is connected.

I know the picture of this looks like the sets $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ looks like a chain in a line.

I have also been trying to do a proof using induction because my professor recommended I do so, but I just can't see it. Please help me out if you can.

Comment: Do you know the equivalent formulation of a connected set as a set $X$ for which the only continuous functions $X\to\{0,1\}$ are constant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $f : \cup_{i = 1}^n A_i\to\{0,1\}$ be continuous, and let $\left.f_i = f\right|_{A_i}$ be the restriction of $f$ to $A_i$. Note that each $f_i$ must be constant. After that, use $A_i\cap A_{i + 1}\neq\emptyset$ to finish off the problem (what can you say about $f$?).